# Create a similar question for a different framework (Unity)

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

There is a well known C# question about *what a `NullReferenceException` is and how to fix it*.

Unity which has the [Unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) tag on Stack Overflow uses C#, but I noticed a-lot of Unity questions with the `NullReferenceException`. This question is asked about more than 10x every week.

When the title of the Unity question include `NullReferenceException`, the question is immediately closed as a duplicate of the other well known question. When `NullReferenceException` is not included in the title, it is not closed most of the time and people get the chance to answer it.

Here are the problems with the known question that is used to close other Unity questions:

- It is mainly helpful to those that use **.NET** and **VB.NET**.
- Because the way of creating new Objects/Scripts instance or accessing already existing
  one in Unity is totally different from a normal C# way, it won't
  solve Unity question 99% of the time.
- Only a few times have I seen that a question and the answers in them was likely to solve Unity question and those times were only when the OP did not inherit from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html).
- When Unity question with this problem is closed, I see nice people still trying to help the OP through the comment section. Sometimes, I do that when I have time since the person having this problem is very likely new to Unity, and I know for sure that the duplicated question won't solve OP's problem.
- The list of reasons for getting `NullReferenceException` in Unity is really long and unique to Unity itself, but it can be arranged in category.
- There are many answers on this question already to the extent that adding Unity one will be hard for Unity users to find when they run into this problem. They will quit programming by the time they finish scrolling down on that page.

When a Unity question with the `NullReferenceException` exception is closed, it brings more confusion to OP because the long accepted answer does not come close to solving the OP's problem. Other answers there are not useful too. It simply does not help and the comment section of that question becomes really long as OP seeks more help.

---

I want to create a `NullReferenceException` question and answer dedicated to Unity programmers that will actually help Unity users but I have two questions:

**1**. With all the things I mentioned above, is it acceptable to create **one** new `NullReferenceException` question and answer for this problem and just for the [Unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) tag? Any Unity programmer can contribute to it. Maybe, explicitly add Unity in the title of the question.

**2**. If so, how do you prevent people from closing it? I noticed that they usually close it just by reading the title.

**Note**:

For those wondering what the solution to this problem is 99% of the time it is asked: The usual solution is to Find the GameObject, and then get the script that is attached to it.

```
GameObject.Find("ObjectName").GetComponent<TheScript>();
```

Now, you see this has nothing to do with the answer from the duplicated question. This is just an example and there are many other reasons and solutions depending on the Unity function used.

I refused to link the original question to prevent the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/204311#204311), but it is likely the first result from a Google search.

Comment: Personally I'd find more use in one big what is a nullxxxexception question, with a common cw answer then a specific cw answer for each platform, and a FAQ style indexed list of answers in the question, e.g. combine the Java and c# and whatever other ones into one q with multiple answers. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: @JasonC When I say "different platform", I was actually referring to Unity itself and it is the-same answer for each platform Unity supports. Are you saying it is better to add the answer to an existing question?

Comment: Unity has some odd ways of handling things with dozens of ways to fix them (`GameObject.Find` being one, and probably the least efficient, but it (usually) works) that aren't all *programatic.*  IMO I would set up a self-answered question that is *Unity-specific* and start pointing all other unity NPE questions to it instead. You could even close your own self-answered question as a dupe *of the existing one* so that non-Unity-specific NPE problems can be directed there if the Unity specific answer(s) don't work. *I'd* thumb a Unity-specific question up (other platforms, probably not).

Comment: @Draco18s When I said "different platform", I actually meant "different" software which is Unity itself rather than Microsoft's WPF or other Microsoft technology that the duplicated question is very useful to. I don't mean creating different questions for iOs, Android, Mac, Linux..... I don't know how to reward that so that I won't confuse people. And yes, it looks like creating a new question and answer for Unity is the solution.

Comment: @Programmer Oh I know what you meant by platform. What I meant was, I don't know if I'd necessarily +1 a similar question specific to [some other appropriate engine/hardware/language here].  But I know that NPEs in Unity are sometimes difficult to diagnose. I've got one in a project right now where Physics.Raycast returns sensible values in the RaycastHit object, but when another script attempts to reference them, they turn into nonsense (ClassCastException, actually, but you get the idea). I can't use standard techniques to debug it and inserting `Debug.Log(...)` *made the error go away.*

Comment: Ok. I see what you mean.

Comment: *For those wondering what the solution to this problem is 99% of the time it is asked:* Sounds like you could go to the canonical and edit the answer to add a section on Unity NREs, if that really covers the vast majority of questions on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That same shalt-not-be-named `NullReferenceException` thread has bothered me from time to time too. It's very thorough, but it doesn't apply perfectly in every case. And to keep appending to it, to make it fit every case... yikes, it's a *behemoth* and will only grow larger.

My suggestion would be to create a canonical question specifically for Unity, and answer it yourself. Even if the thread is closed, the answer can still be edited.

I know SO usually discourages tags in titles, but I don't know how to avoid it here, especially if someone might create similar canonical threads for other technologies in the future. Maybe start with something like this?

> **How do I fix a NullReferenceException in Unity?**
>
> I frequently encounter NullReferenceException errors in Unity. I found the [canonical answer for this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), but the answers in there usually don't fix my Unity-specific problems, such as:
>
> - this one place you might see it in Unity,
> - that other place you'll see it too, and
> - yet another place you'll tend to see it
>
> How can I fix this exception when I'm developing a Unity app?
>
> <kbd>unity3d</kbd> <kbd>null</kbd> <kbd>nullreferenceexception</kbd>

I think one master answer would work, similar to the highest-voted answer on the other thread. Just start listing common situations in Unity that throw that exception, and the best way to find the cause and resolve it.

At this point, that other thread has so much google karma that any search for just "NullReferenceException" will return it. But it wouldn't hurt (and might be less intimidating) for more specific searches like "NullReferenceException in Unity" to return a more tailored thread.

Answer (score 1):

In response to question 1, I think this is a bit opinion based, but I would argue that there should definitely be a Unity specific question given that it is a different question..

In response to question 2, a clearly marked title stating that it is a "Unity Specific" problem could help. Also starting the piece with a clear indication that the normal C# question does not address the issue could make things clearer. Even with this, people still may close the question, but it can be reopened if closing it is a mistake, so the question should reopened if this is the issue.

Comment: "Even with this, people still may close the question" ...Well, that's the problem and I forgot the re-open button. Although it can be closed again when re-opened....