# Can a reference question be used as a dupe target?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

Here’s the specific problem I’m trying to tackle:

Roughly once a week, someone ends up posting a question along the lines of “Help! My GraphQL endpoint is returning null!” Unfortunately, the questions themselves are often specific to some particular stack, even when the answers boil down to roughly one of two common issues.

There’s dozens of these questions littering the site. A search for `graphql null` returns 1142 posts. A quick scan of the first 50 results shows almost half fall into this category of questions:

- [GraphQL returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817116/graphql-returning-null)
- [GraphQL returns null on mutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54524105/graphql-returns-null-on-mutation)
- [Graphql schema returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347983/graphql-schema-returning-null)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317617/graphql-query-returning-null-fields
- [GraphQL Schema and Resolvers organization return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233503/graphql-schema-and-resolvers-organization-return-null)
- [Node GraphQL resolve null data from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217483/node-graphql-resolve-null-data-from-api)
- [graphql query return object with null id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54265325/graphql-query-return-object-with-null-id)
- [Cannot return null for non-nullable field, GraphQl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469707/cannot-return-null-for-non-nullable-field-graphql)
- [GraphQL showing Value as null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905825/graphql-showing-value-as-null)
- [Why is my Graphql query returning null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044031/why-is-my-graphql-query-returning-null)
- [GraphQL Apollo Cannot Return Null for non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997278/graphql-apollo-cannot-return-null-for-non-nullable)
- [graphql mongoose returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619241/graphql-mongoose-returning-null)
- [GraphQL relationship returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749806/graphql-relationship-returning-null)
- [graphql is only resolving _id field, other fields are null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010618/graphql-is-only-resolving-id-field-other-fields-are-null)
- [graphQL query give me null object in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701278/graphql-query-give-me-null-object-in-response)
- [Apollo/Graphql, Postgres - Why is this query returning null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55525114/apollo-graphql-postgres-why-is-this-query-returning-null)
- [GraphQL + Sequelize resolver giving null data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824756/graphql-sequelize-resolver-giving-null-data)
- [Getting "Cannot return null" error while querying API using Graphql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56069223/getting-cannot-return-null-error-while-querying-api-using-graphql)
- [GraphQL returning null data from axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589649/graphql-returning-null-data-from-axios)
- [GraphQL: Rootquery returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021191/graphql-rootquery-returns-null)
- [Why is this GraphQL query returning null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888377/why-is-this-graphql-query-returning-null)

I feel like these posts provide little value to the site, which is evidenced by how few upvotes they get. As a user, it’s not likely that searching for “GraphQL returning null” is going to lead me to a high-quality question/answer that applies to my particular problem.

As far as I’m aware, there’s not already a reference question related to this issue, I think we would benefit from one and I'm contemplating writing one.

**However, even if there’s value in creating the reference question, I’m not sure if it’s appropriate to use it as a dupe target.**

Even if the provided answer is thorough and includes examples, there’s the risk that the OP of the dupe might not be able to apply the examples to their specific issue. Is it enough to just provide some additional direction in the comments before closing the question? Even if using the reference question as a dupe target creates a suboptimal experience for some users, is that outweighed by a cleaner site and a better search experience for future users?

EDIT:

Thank you everyone for your feedback. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319137/why-does-a-graphql-query-return-null) is the post I ended up composing in case anyone wants to take a gander.

Comment: (1) Related: [*Create a similar question for a different framework (Unity)*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349539), and various other results from searching for "NullPointerException" on Meta. (2) "Can a reference question be used as a dupe target?" -- Yes, as long as it actually answers the question. That is a common motivation for creating reference questions. (3) "Is it enough to just provide some additional direction in the comments before closing the question?" -- Generally, yes. If you are hammering, the comment should be posted immediately *after* closure -- there is no need to wait.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose, this is something that is already being done to tackle certain groups of questions with common rootcauses.

Comment: Somehow missed duplode's comment but I guess more reading material never hurts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you *can* write a canonical Q&A pair that clearly explains the problem, and then (as the answer) answers it.  **This is a good thing, and makes it a *better* duplicate target than a messy question with lots of other bugs that answers will also spend time on.**  Choose a title that says what the problem is, because that's the title is the first thing people will see when their duplicate questions get closed.

If you find yourself struggling to cover all the possible cases for potential duplicates in one answer, it might be a sign that they're not all exact duplicates, and maybe you need to split it up into a couple related things.  But if that doesn't happen, then great.

This is useful in cases like you describe, where the real underlying problem is buried under implementation detail and mixed in with other bugs in all the existing questions.

It's generally better to find an existing question that either has a good answer, or that you can just answer, but if you can't (because they're too messy and full of extraneous detail).  So don't write a new question without spending some time searching first.  Looking over the existing questions can sometimes help see what points people are not understanding that led to asking in the first place, guiding your efforts in writing a canonical.

---

**Sometimes you can just retitle one of the existing questions** (because a good question title is critical for a good dup target), if the question body and answer don't waste too much time on unrelated stuff.

When you close a question as a duplicate, it looks like nonsense if the title is "trying to write a tic-tac-toe game" instead of "what happens if you leave out the `ret` instruction at the end of a function?" or something.  Often when I go searching for a dup target (and there's not an existing well-established canonical duplicate), I end up retitling the dup target question to put the real problem in the title.  (And if I see any, minor cleanups to the question and/or answer while I'm at it.)

---

> even when the answers boil down to roughly one of two common issues.

Sounds like you should identify separate canonical Q&As for those problems then.  If none of the existing ones are good, then sure write a new one or two.

And link all the existing questions as duplicates of the canonical ones, at least after you wait a couple days for feedback from the rest of the tag community.  (Especially if you have a dup-hammer in the tag.)

---

I've written one such Q&A pair intended as a canonical duplicate for a not-uncommon assembly question which kept coming up in the context of very confused questions from people trying to accomplish some specific task, so the questions were never really trying to ask about this: [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code)

As usual for me, it got quite long (including the question part) :/  So it may not be the best example.  But I will note that **bolding the "make it work" solution at the top of the answer is very important**.  The full details and deep dive into the issue is there for anyone who's interested and wants to learn more, but people who aren't interested have already solved their problem and left.

---

When you *do* find a good canonical, if it was hard to find then add a link to the appropriate tag wiki so you or others can find it again.  For example, the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has a FAQ / canonicals section.  (But probably could use some pruning and sorting, and maybe multiple levels of indentation for its lists; it's large and full of useful stuff, but I'd hesitate to hold it up as a great example.  Still, it's very useful to me for finding certain canonicals which come up repeatedly, but where the google results aren't the question I want.)

Comment: Note, that having an answer that answers the question is not enough. If the reader has to wave through a bunch of unrelated information to find their answer, we aren't saving time of future readers, but squandering it. Both questions have to be semantically the same to be considered duplicates.

Comment: @Braiam I’m sympathetic to this point of view, which is largely why I wrote this question to begin with. On the other hand, is having to wade through hundreds of posts when initially searching for an answer the lesser evil? I’m fairly new to meta, but based on [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315293) [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254697/when-can-a-question-be-closed-as-a-duplicate-of-another?rq=1) I was under the impression that the community opinion generally leaned toward “if they’ve got the same answer” rather than “if they’re semantically equivalent”

Comment: @DanielRearden: Braim's point was that "the answer's in there somewhere as part of an answer to a broader question" isn't good.  If that's the case, you should post an answer that links the near-duplicate and highlights the key point.